# How to use Log in Android

Tags: java, android

I am learning android and i would like check data by function Log.

Now i have code: http://cecs.wright.edu/~pmateti/Courses/436/Lectures/20110920/SimpleNetworking/src/com/androidbook/simplenetworking/FlickrActivity2.java.txt

This working ok, Log.i also, but i would like add own Log:

```
                XmlPullParserFactory parserCreator = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser parser = parserCreator.newPullParser();

                parser.setInput(text.openStream(), null);

                status.setText("Parsing...");
                int parserEvent = parser.getEventType();
                while (parserEvent != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

  //START MY CODE!!!

   XmlPullParser.START_TAG
   Log.i("Test1", parserEvent);
   Log.i("Test2", XmlPullParser.START_TAG);

  //END MY CODE!!!

                    switch(parserEvent) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        String tag = parser.getName();
                        if (tag.compareTo("link") == 0) {
                            String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rel");
                            if (relType.compareTo("enclosure") == 0 ) {
                                String encType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "type");
                                if (encType.startsWith("image/")) {
                                    String imageSrc = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
                                    Log.i("Net", "image source = " + imageSrc);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    parserEvent = parser.next();

                }
                status.setText("Done...");
```

but i have error:

> The method i(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the
>   arguments (String, int)

Why the second parameter is int? How can i check value with Log same as in JavaScript console.log?

Comment: @darkik just use concatenation for eg Log.i(TAG,'  '+variable) simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java, unlike Javascript, is a strongly typed language. The compiler checks that you are providing variables of the expected type to a method. In this case, the method `Log.i` takes two strings as arguments.

You are trying to print an int and thus need to convert it to a string. This can be done like that for instance:

```
Log.i("Test2", Integer.toString(XmlPullParser.START_TAG));
```

Before diving too deep into Android, maybe you should follow a short introduction to the Java language to get the basics right. This will save you time later on.